# mongoose findOneAndUpdate returns twice with null on first?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

this is my code:

```
router.post('/update_todo', async (req, res) => {
  const { todoId, userId, complete } = req.body;
  try {
    const todo = await Todo.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: todoId, userId },
      { $set: { complete: !complete } },
      { new: true } // return latest
    ).populate('userId', '_id');
    console.log('todo pdated', todo)
    res.json({ todo })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error })
  }
})
```

when i try to log, it's returning twice?

```
todo pdated null
todo pdated { complete: true,
_id: 5c003223ec8c1350b8c77b4f,
text: 'wearasdasd asd 2222',
userId: { _id: 5bf3b0b676bcc8176422e94e },
createdAt: 2018-11-29T18:38:27.156Z,
updatedAt: 2018-11-29T23:31:57.022Z,
__v: 0 }
```

what is causing this code to return twice when i am using async/await?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
router.post('/update_todo', async (req, res) => {
  const { todoId, userId, complete } = req.body;
  try {

      Todo.findOneAndUpdate({_id: todoId,userId:userId},{$set:{complete: !complete}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
        }
        console.log('todo updated', doc)
        res.json({ doc })
     });

} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess, although your question lacks enough data to be sure: I don think it is an issue with async/await, but your code is running twice because browser makes Preflight OPTION request:

> ... "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS
>   method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine
>   whether the actual request is safe to send.

To prevent that, I suggest this piece of code in a CORS scenario that returns the OPTIONS request before the system reaches out your business logic:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  ...
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```